# How to define a new column in a stored procedure query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure which realizes a pivot table. My `Select` statement was defined in a variable `@query`.

Here is the code:

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @colNo nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WITH vals AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT t.No
        FROM QR_Tests t
    )

    SELECT @colNo = COALESCE(@colNo + ', ', '') + '['+ No +']'
    FROM vals
    ORDER BY No

    SET @query = 'SELECT *
                  FROM (
                    SELECT 
                        CASE WHEN GROUPING(No) = 0
                            THEN CAST(No as CHAR(12))
                        ELSE [ALL]
                        END As No,
                        CASE WHEN GROUPING(quote) = 0
                            THEN CAST(quote as CHAR(7))
                        ELSE [ALL]
                        END As Quote
                    FROM QRTestView
                    WHERE datum >= @from_val and datum <= @to_val
                    GROUP BY No, Quote WITH CUBE) AS sel
                    PIVOT (
                        COUNT(Quote)
                        FOR No IN ('+ @colNo +', [ALL])
                    ) AS p'

    EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@from_val datetime, @to_val datetime', @from_val = @from, @to_val = @to
END
```

I need the following result practically:

```
| Quote | DE10101 | DE10121 | DE22034 | ... | ALL
|  100  |    2    |    0    |    3    | ... |  5
|   99  |    0    |    4    |    3    | ... |  7
|   98  |    5    |    1    |    7    | ... | 13
|   90  |    0    |    0    |    1    | ... |  1
|   50  |   12    |   10    |    4    | ... | 26
|  ALL  |   19    |   15    |   18    | ... | 52
```

I tried an example from this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2007/09/27/aggregation-with-cube/). When I execute the stored procedure, then I'm getting the error message:

> invalid column name 'ALL'.

How can I define this new column for my result?

---

UPDATE:
To understand the transformation, here the source table:

```
| No      | Quote | Datum
| DE10101 | 100   | 2016-01-01
| DE10121 | 100   | 2016-01-02
| DE10101 | 100   | 2016-01-05
| DE22034 | 98    | 2016-01-05
| DE10101 | 98    | 2016-01-10
| DE10121 | 80    | 2016-01-10
| DE22034 | 98    | 2016-01-10
| DE22034 | 80    | 2016-01-11
| DE10101 | 100   | 2016-01-20
| DE10121 | 80    | 2016-01-21
```

And this should be the result:

```
| Quote | DE10101 | DE10121 | DE22034 | ALL
| 100   |    3    |    1    |    0    |  4
|  98   |    1    |    0    |    2    |  3
|  80   |    0    |    2    |    1    |  3
| ALL   |    4    |    3    |    3    | 10
```

Currently the stored procedure doesn't count the amount of quotes for every `No`.

Comment: What does the table look like ? are you sure there is [ALL] column ?

Comment: @HynekBernard [ALL] should be the new column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand `ALL` is the sum of all values in this row. So you need to rewrite your SP code (based on data you provided):

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @colNo nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @colSum nvarchar(max) -- this will store [Column1]+[Column2] etc
    DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WITH vals AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT t.No
        FROM QR_Tests t
    )

    SELECT  @colNo = COALESCE(@colNo + ', ', '') + QUOTENAME([No]),
            @colSum = COALESCE(@colSum + '+ ', '') + QUOTENAME([No])
    FROM vals
    ORDER BY [No]
    -- add this column here
    SET @query = 'SELECT *
                  FROM (
                    SELECT *, '+@colSum+' as [ALL] 
                    FROM (
                        SELECT 
                            CAST([No] as CHAR(12)) As No,
                            CAST(quote as CHAR(7)) As Quote,
                            CAST(quote as CHAR(7)) As Q
                        FROM QRTestView
                        WHERE datum >= @from_val and datum <= @to_val
                        ) AS sel
                    PIVOT (
                        COUNT(Q) FOR No IN ('+ @colNo +')
                    ) AS p
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT ''ALL'',*, '+@colSum+'[ALL] 
                    FROM (
                        SELECT 
                            CAST([No] as CHAR(12)) As No,
                            COUNT(CAST(quote as CHAR(7))) As Quote,
                        FROM QRTestView
                        WHERE datum >= @from_val and datum <= @to_val
                        GROUP BY CAST([No] as CHAR(12))
                        ) AS sel
                    PIVOT (
                        MAX(Quote) FOR [No] IN ('+ @colNo +')
                    ) AS p
               ) as d
               ORDER BY CASE WHEN Quote = ''ALL'' THEN 0 ELSE CAST(Quote as int) END DESC'

    EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@from_val datetime, @to_val datetime', @from_val 
END
```

Comment: one second I will try your solution and yes the column `[ALL]` represents the sum of the values :)

Comment: The Procedure doesn't select the column `Quote`. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: Because you use `COUNT(Quote)` in pivoting. I guess your SP returns just 1 row.

Comment: Yes, it does! I will edit my post, so that you can understand it better.

Comment: I add one more column in your PIVOT part. Please, give it a try. It is a column copy of `[Quote]`

Comment: I've edited my post. Could you please look to the source table above :)

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't COUNT the amoung of quotes for every No :(

Comment: Hey, now I understand. I add a sample to my answer.

Comment: So, I'm getting the error message: `invalid column name "Q", All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.` :(

Comment: Sorry, instead `MAX(Q)` - need to use `MAX(Quote)` in the last PIVOT. Changed answer!

Comment: yeeeeeessss you are the man!!!!! Thanksss. I still have one question only. How can I sort the table by Quote. I tried `ORDER BY Quote DESC` at the end of the second PIVOT but it gets FIRST ALL, 99,98... but I need 100,99,98....,1,0,ALL. Do you know what I mean? (After that I will mark your answer as solution my friend :))))

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you use? If 2012 there is a way with `TRY_CAST`. I add this to answer

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008R2

Comment: Ok, changed answer :) `ORDER BY CASE WHEN Quote = 'ALL' THEN 0 ELSE CAST(Quote as int) END DESC`

Comment: You are the best! Only as information. How can I change it, when I want to display the row "ALL" firstly and then the rest (100,99,98,97...)?

Comment: Just change `THEN 0 ` on `THEN 1000000000 ` or some other int value that is over `MAX(Quote)`

Comment: I will open a new Question to an extension of this result table soon. How can I contact you for other questions regarding T-SQL? :)

Comment: You can post your question and post link here in comments, or maybe I will find it by myself :) I usually answer/comment here when I am free on my main work.

Comment: Thanks for your help! You saved my day :)

Comment: The new thread is opened :) -> [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631285/create-new-columns-in-a-declared-query-variable-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

In your case statements you need to change `[ALL]` to `'ALL'`, remembering to use two single quotes as you are building a string value:

```
SET @query = 'SELECT *
                  FROM (
                    SELECT 
                        CASE WHEN GROUPING(No) = 0
                            THEN CAST(No as CHAR(12))
                        ELSE ''ALL''
                        END As No,
                        CASE WHEN GROUPING(quote) = 0
                            THEN CAST(quote as CHAR(7))
                        ELSE ''ALL''
                        END As Quote
                    FROM QRTestView
                    WHERE datum >= @from_val and datum <= @to_val
                    GROUP BY No, Quote WITH CUBE) AS sel
                    PIVOT (
                        COUNT(Quote)
                        FOR No IN ('+ @colNo +', [ALL])
                    ) AS p'
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do you have an idea why the SProc doesn't show the column `Quote` in the result?