# Create new columns in a declared query variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I've created a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2. It executes a pivot table. So, what I need for the next steps are 3 new columns, which would be create in this declared query variable. In these 3 columns I have to perform a calculation.

At first, my stored procedures code:
UPDATE Stored Procedure:

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @colNo nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @colSum nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WITH vals AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT ds.No
        FROM QRTestView ds
    )

    SELECT @colNo = COALESCE(@colNo + ', ', '') + QUOTENAME(No)
           @colSum = COALESCE(@colSum + '+ ', '') + QUOTENAME(No)
    FROM vals
    ORDER BY No

    SET @query = 'SELECT *, [Bonus] + 125 as [Fee], 
                   ([Bonus] + 125) * [ALL] as [Fee2]
                    FROM (
                      SELECT *,
                        CASE WHEN 70-(100 - Quote) * 10 > -80 THEN 70-(100 - Quote) * 10  ELSE -70 END as [Bonus]
                      FROM (
                        SELECT *, '+@colSum+' as [ALL]
                        FROM (
                          SELECT 
                             CAST(ISIN as CHAR(12)) As No,
                             CAST(Quote as CHAR(7)) As Quote,
                             CAST(Quote as CHAR(7)) As Q
                          FROM QRTestView
                          WHERE Datum >= @from_val and Datum <= @to_val
                        ) AS sel
                        PIVOT (
                          COUNT(Q)
                          FOR No IN ('+ @colNo +')
                        ) AS p

                      UNION ALL

                      SELECT ''ALL'', *, '+@colSum+'[ALL]
                      FROM (
                        SELECT
                           CAST(No as CHAR(12)) As No,
                           COUNT(CAST(Quote as CHAR(7))) As Quote
                        FROM QRTestView
                        WHERE Datum >= @from_val and Datum <= @to_val
                        GROUP BY CAST(No as CHAR(12))
                      ) AS sel
                      PIVOT (
                        MAX(Quote) 
                        FOR No in ('+ @colNo +')
                      ) AS p
                     ) AS sel2
                  ) as ff

            ORDER BY CASE WHEN Quote = ''ALL'' THEN 101 ELSE CAST(Quote as INT) END DESC'

    EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@from_val datetime, @to_val datetime', @from_val = @from, @to_val = @to
END
```

To understand the question, I will show you the source table:

```
| No      | Quote | Datum
| DE10101 | 100   | 2016-01-01
| DE10121 | 100   | 2016-01-02
| DE10101 | 100   | 2016-01-05
| DE22034 | 98    | 2016-01-05
| DE10101 | 98    | 2016-01-10
| DE10121 | 80    | 2016-01-10
| DE22034 | 98    | 2016-01-10
| DE22034 | 80    | 2016-01-11
| DE10101 | 100   | 2016-01-20
| DE10121 | 80    | 2016-01-21
```

And the target table has 3 additional columns:

```
| Quote | DE10101 | DE10121 | DE22034 | ALL | Bonus | Fee | Fee2 |
| 100   |    3    |    1    |    0    |  4  |  70   | 195 | 780  |
|  98   |    1    |    0    |    2    |  3  |  50   | 175 | 525  |
|  80   |    0    |    2    |    1    |  3  | -70   |  55 | 165  |
| ALL   |    4    |    3    |    3    | 10  |       |     | 1470 |
```

the 3 new columns are: `Bonus, Fee, Fee2`

The calculation works as follows:

Bonus: 
`WHEN 70-(100 - Quote) * 10 > -80
 THEN 70-(100 - Quote) * 10
 ELSE -70`

Fee:
`Bonus + 125`

Fee2:
`ALL * Fee`

How can I define these 3 columns and calculation in my query variable in the stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use CTE

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @colNo nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @SUMCols nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)


SET NOCOUNT ON;

WITH vals AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ds.[No]
    FROM QRTestView ds
)

SELECT @colNo = COALESCE(@colNo + ', ', '') + QUOTENAME([No]),
       @SUMCols = COALESCE(@SUMCols + ', ', '') + 'SUM(' + QUOTENAME([No]) +')'
FROM vals
ORDER BY No


SELECT @query = N'
;WITH cte as (
SELECT  *, 
        [Bonus] + 125 as [Fee], 
        ([Bonus] + 125) * [ALL] as [Fee2]
FROM (
    SELECT  *,
            CASE WHEN 70-(100 - Quote) * 10 > -80 THEN 70-(100 - Quote) * 10  ELSE -70 END as [Bonus]
    FROM (
        SELECT  *, 
                '+REPLACE(@colNo,',','+')+'  as [ALL]
        FROM (
            SELECT  CAST(No as CHAR(12)) As No,
                    CAST(Quote as CHAR(7)) As Quote,
                    CAST(Quote as CHAR(7)) As Q
            FROM QRTestView
            WHERE Datum >= @from_val and Datum <= @to_val
            ) AS sel
            PIVOT (
                COUNT(Q)
                FOR No IN ('+@colNo+')
            ) AS p
        ) AS d
    ) as ff
)

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  *
    FROM cte
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  ''ALL'', 
            '+@SUMCols+'
            SUM([ALL]),
            NULL,
            NULL,
            SUM(Fee2)
    FROM cte
    ) as t
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Quote = ''ALL'' THEN 101 ELSE CAST(Quote as INT) END DESC'

EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@from_val datetime, @to_val datetime', @from_val = @from, @to_val = @to
```

Comment: Very nice! Is it possible to define the calculation as a declared variable a bit shorter?

Comment: Yes, you can. But with one more sub-query. See edits.

Comment: in my last thread, could I do this with `UNION ALL`? I mean this thread -> [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607931/how-to-define-a-new-column-in-a-stored-procedure-query)

Comment: I've tried it in the second SELECT statement but I'm getting the error: `All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.` Could you please make an update in the last thread for these 3 columns! It would be very great :)

Comment: Or I could edit my thread with the other stored procedure? What is better for you?

Comment: For me is better if you make it by yourself :) I add more info to my answer

Comment: At first, thanks for your support! it is very helpful for me. So, I have updated my post above, especially the stored procedure in my post. I'm getting the error: `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ALL' to data type int`

Comment: verrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrry nice :). My last question and then you're free from me :D for the column `Fee2` I need the sum of this column. Currently I get 'NULL'

Comment: If you'll use SQL Server 2012 there will be SUM() OVER (ORDER BY..) and thats all... but you are using 2008 R2...

Comment: Is there not a possibility? On which position I have to define it? Then I will try it.

Comment: Yes it is :) I add this to my answer.

Comment: I have some problems with my stored procedure. I will edit my post.. one moment sorry :(

Comment: `@SUMCols` is nowhere used. In the last SELECT you've written the No's separatly?!

Comment: :) just change all sum's with [No] to this variable, it was a testing sample. Changed in answer :)

Comment: I've changed it as follows: `SELECT ''ALL'',
         SUM('+ @colNo +'),
         NULL,
         NULL,
         SUM([Fee2])
     FROM cte` but it doesn't work. I have also add [No] instead of @colNo but this is also wrong :(

Comment: Hey, look in my answer, I changed this thing for you :)

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! It works. One question. How long did you need to be a professional tsql programmer? :) Could you explain me only the steps of the query? It would be helpful to understand :)

Comment: Few years, I guess (at least for me). The main thing - study all that you don't know really hard. The query: At first you collect data you need and pivot it, you need dynamic SQL or else write all the columns you need by hands. Then we put our results in subquery to get bonuses counted, then another subquery to count Fee, all this we put in cte so we don't need to use same query twice. After this we select all from this cte and add Union with sums.